# Help - how to create a "quick poll" web part

Tags: web-part

I would be creating a simple "quick poll" web part (single selection). I'm hoping if someone has tried it and could tell me how he/she figured it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to advertise for the company, I have no connections with them at all, but I guess you'll have to take a look at the free webparts of Amrein (http://www.amrein.com/). The free webparts include a Quick Poll and a Quick Survey.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a webpart for the same and you can view it at the following link
http://asharepointsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/07/quick-poll-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not prefer the Survey (it might do it, if you need a simple thing), my all favorite (for doing it yourself) is by using a Data-View WebPart and customize it.
Use either : http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.ch/2011/06/how-to-create-sharepoint-2010-polling.html
or https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/create-a-polling-web-part-with-sharepoint-designer-and-the-dvwp.aspx